# When generating a 4096 bit RSA key pair, do both the private and the public key always have exactly 4096 bits?

Tags: rsa

When generating a 4096 bit RSA key pair, do both the private and the public key always have **exactly** 4096 bits, thus do not start with a 0 in binary representation?

Answer (score 4):

As a preliminary, in RSA the public key is the pair `(N, e)` and the private key is `d`. Like it has been stated, the bit size of the modulus `N` is what the 4096 refers to. `N` only makes up part of the public key, along with `e`. There is no requirement for what bit size `e` is. The only requirement for secure encryption in RSA is that exponentiating the message `m` to the `e`th power "wraps the modulus", i.e. `m^e > N`. So in practice values of `e` as small as 3 (2 bits) have been used. The most common current value for `e` is 65537 (17 bits) in fact most SSL certs that you see have this value e.g. google.com

[image]

The bit size of `d`, the private key, is not set and can vary greatly as it is simply the multiplicative inverse of `e` in the group `phi(N)` where phi is the totient function. In most cases it will be much smaller than 4096 bits.

Comment: Your last statement claiming that in most cases d will be much smaller than 4096 bits is incorrect. ￼￼￼d will be approximately uniformly distributed over the range from 1 to φ(n), and φ(n) is not much smaller than n. So on average d will be close to n/2, which means if n is 4096 bits d will be around 4095 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Expect Zeros to occur in the MSB or LSB of the BigInteger.  (either end of the binary output)

I've written RSA code in C# and had to account for a leading zero in BouncyCastle BigInteger and .NET Big Integer.  What is interesting about the two libraries is that one is Big Endian, the other Little Endian.

Comment: Lamonte - if you want to know about the leading zero probability, that would likely be better served over on Crypto Stack Exchange

Comment: @RoryAlsop Will ask there ;)

Comment: Cool. Our typical rule of thumb is that if it is the maths or theory then Crypto should have it. Implementation is on topic here.

Comment: Found it, the leading zero occurs 1/256 times http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26648/371

Answer (score 0):

4096 refers to the [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29) of n. The public key and the private key should be of "similar" bit length in order to provide the intended security. Choosing a significantly smaller value for either **p** or **q** allows for the factorization of **n**(i.e. through brute forcing) and can thus be used to retrieve the secret key.

Consequently, it is necessary for both parameters to have the mentioned length.